# Adding data to line in CSV if value exists in external file

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop

Here is my sample data:

```
1,32425,New Zealand,number,21004
1,32425,New Zealand,number,20522
1,32434,Australia,number,1542
1,32434,Australia,number,986
1,32434,Fiji,number,1
```

Here is my expected output:

```
1,32425,New Zealand,number,21004,No
1,32425,New Zealand,number,20522,No
1,32434,Australia,number,1542,No
1,32434,Australia,number,986,No
1,32434,Fiji,number,1,Yes
```

Basically I am trying to append the Yes/No based on if field 3 is contained in an external file. Here is what I have currently but as I understand it grep is eating all the stdin in the while loop. So I am only getting No added to the end of each line as the first value is not contained in the external file.

```
while IFS=, read -r type id country number volume
do
  if grep $country externalfile.csv
  then
    echo "${country}"
    sed 's/$/,Yes/' >> file2.csv
  else
    echo "${country}"
    sed 's/$/,No/' >> file2.csv
  fi
done < file1.csv
```

I added the echo "${country}" as I was trying to troubleshoot and that's how I discovered it was only parsing the first line.

Comment: What does the other file look like? How big is it? I'd probably parse it into a lookup table to avoid all those calls to `grep`.

Comment: There's about 240 lines, and each line is just one country name.

Comment: The `-q` flag from `grep` is missing.

Comment: Also if there are say `1k` lines then `grep` and `sed` will also run `1k` times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
while read -r line
do
country=`echo $line | cut -d',' -f3`
if grep "$country" externalfile.csv
then
        echo "$line,Yes" >> file2.csv
else
        echo "$line,No" >> file2.csv
fi
done < test.txt
```

You need to put `$country` inside the `"`, because some country could contains more than 1 word. For example New Zealand. You can also set `country` variable easier using `cut` command.

Comment: Works great! Just so I understand, this works because we set the variable within the while loop, whereas previously I was reading from the variable set by while which was consuming the rest of the stdin?

Comment: This is easiest way to catch interesting data. Try this in the terminal: `echo "1,32425,New Zealand,number,20522" | cut -d',' -f3`. You can look how it works ;) In the loop you are now reading whole line and the you are cutting specific field.

Comment: This will still run `grep` on every line of `file2.csv`. That's not very kind to the machine.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there are no headers -

```
 awk -F, 'NR==FNR{lookup[$1]=$1; next;}
   { if ( lookup[$3] == $3 ) { print $0 ",Yes" } else { print $0 ",No" } }
         ' externalfile.csv file2.csv
```

This will parse both files in one pass.

If you just prefer to do it in pure `bash`,

```
declare -A lookup
while read c; do lookup["$c"]="$c"; done < externalfile.csv

declare -p lookup # this is just to show you what my example loaded
declare -A lookup='([USA]="USA" [Fiji]="Fiji" )'

while IFS=, read a b c d; do 
  [[ -n "${lookup[$c]}" ]] && echo "$a,$b,$c,$d,Yes" || echo "$a,$b,$c,$d,No"
done < file2.csv
1,32425,New Zealand,number,21004,No
1,32425,New Zealand,number,20522,No
1,32434,Australia,number,1542,No
1,32434,Australia,number,986,No
1,32434,Fiji,number,1,Yes
```

No `grep` needed.

Comment: Alternatively, `{ print $0, ($3 in lookup ? "Yes" : "No") }
` with `-v OFS=","`

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR == FNR { ++a[$1]; next } { $(++NF) = $3 in a ? "Yes" : "No" } 1' externalfile.csv file2.csv
```